# How can I use IN() clause in the INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN pivot pi on p.id = pi.post_id
INNER JOIN tags t on t.id = pi.tag_id and t.name = "mysql"
```

All I'm trying to do is getting posts that are tagged with a specific tag. In query above, I'm selecting all posts with `mysql` tag.

---

Now I need to make it working for multiple-tags. I mean, I want to select all post which are tagged with both `mysql` and `php`. I guess I have to use `IN()` clause in the query. But I don't know how exactly. Any idea?

---

**EX:** Here are my tables:

```
// posts
+----+---------+------------+
| id | subject |    body    |
+----+---------+------------+
| 1  | sub1    | content1   |
| 2  | sub2    | content2   |
+----+---------+------------+

// tags
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | mysql  |
| 2  | php    |
+----+--------+

// pivot 
+---------+--------+
| post_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 1      |
| 2       | 1      |
| 2       | 2      |
+---------+--------+
```

The expected result for `[mysql]`:

```
| 1  | sub1    | content1   |
| 2  | sub2    | content2   |
```

The expected result for `[mysql][php]`:

```
| 2  | sub2    | content2   |
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: add a second inner join, one for each tag. otherwise you get a logical OR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `WHERE` clause for the conditions and then aggregation:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     pivot pi 
     ON p.id = pi.post_id INNER JOIN
     tags t 
     ON t.id = pi.tag_id 
WHERE t.name IN ('mysql', 'php')
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;  -- this is the number of tags in the list
```

This assumes that tags are not duplicated.

A note about using `GROUP BY p.id` with `SELECT p.*`.  This is actually valid and allowed by the ANSI standard, assuming that `p.id` is unique in `posts`.  The specific rule is based on functional dependency.

I do think the most recent versions of MySQL disallow the construct by default.  You can always do something like:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p JOIN
     (SELECT pi.post_id
      FROM pivot pi INNER JOIN
           tags t 
           ON t.id = pi.tag_id 
      WHERE t.name IN ('mysql', 'php')
      GROUP BY p.id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2  -- this is the number of tags in the list
     ) t
     ON p.id = t.post_id ;
```

Comment: I don't understand the reason of using *aggregation*. Why exactly?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . Because you need to combine data on different rows.  The tag information is on different trows.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you, upvote. Just  as a consult, is your approach more optimal or Joel approach? You know, this query would be created dynamically, also I don't use any query builder, so Joel approach is much more easy to be created dynamically. But I don't know about the performance. Which one?

Comment: The `group_concat()` method  is very similar in performance -- if you filter before doing the concatenation.  It is nice, but (1) doesn't generalize to other databases and (2) the code as written requires an `ORDER BY` to work correctly.  As for the `join` version, you have to test it.  `JOIN` quite possibly works better for two tags, but the performance degrades as the number of tags increase.  The performance of the aggregation solutions is much less dependent on the number of tags.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why should we complicate this ..

Instade of in clause just use string input to query and compare it with string aggregate.

```
SELECT *
FROM posts P
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT post_id, CONCAT ("(", Group_concat(t.name SEPARATOR ' ,'), ")") AS tgs
   FROM pivote p
   INNER JOIN tag t
   ON (t.id = p.tag_id)
   GROUP BY post_id
   ) AA
 ON P.id = post_id
 WHERE tgs LIKE "(mysql,php)
```

Comment: Your query returns posts that are  tagged only with `php`, when you pass both `mysql` and `php`.

Comment: Yes.. I got my mistake but now I have changed my logic accordingly .. just check it once .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select all post which are tagged with both mysql and php. I guess I have to use IN() clause in the query.

Nope. That would show you posts which are tagged one or the other. To find posts with *both*, I would join to the tables twice:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN pivot pi1 on p.id = pi1.post_id
INNER JOIN tags t1 on t1.id = pi1.tag_id and t1.name = "mysql"
INNER JOIN pivot pi2 on p.id = pi2.post_id
INNER JOIN tags t2 on t2.id = pi2.tag_id and t2.name = "php"
```

...

Comment: You know, the policy of my website is filtering questions based utmost 5 tags, so in the maximum situation, my query will be containing 10 joins. Is it normal? Is Gordon approach more optimal or yours?! Thank you anyway, upvote

Comment: Noted that this query supposed to be created dynamically, and your approach is easier to be created dynamically, it's just appending 2 joins to the end of query per tag. But I'm worried about the performance. Which one anyway to your opinion? (Also in the most of times people just search in the whole posts  and filtering rarely happens in reality)

Comment: In this case, go with Gordon's answer (seems like you already did).

Comment: Nope .. I went with your approach and modified the policy of my website a bit (I reduced the upmost number from 5 tags to 3 tags). Just one thing, are you sure you should join to `pivot` table twice? Can't you do that once?

Comment: You could do it just once if the next step were a left join. But doing an inner join will cull the pivot records with the wrong tag_id